# Bash how to replace nth character in a string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a string with in a file:

```
"1.0.0.0.5";
```

I would like to replace 5 with 6 so the output should look like

```
"1.0.0.0.6";
```

could you please help me in this to achieve the output as above in bash

Comment: Replace 5 with 6 so it becomes 4? That's impossible

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that what you really want to do is **increment** the 5th dot-delimited **field** in that line.

```bash
line='"1.0.0.0.5";'
if [[ $line =~ \"([^\"]+) ]]; then 
    IFS="." read -ra fields <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    ((++fields[-1]))
    (
        IFS="."
        printf '"%s";\n' "${fields[*]}"
    )
fi
```

```
"1.0.0.0.6";
```

Answer (score 0):

`bash` doesn't have an operator for assigning to a string index. So you'll need to concatenate the portions before and after the index you want to replace.

```
s=1.0.0.0.5
s=${s:0:8}6${s:9:}
```

`${s:0:8}` means the first 8 characters, and `${s:9:}` means all the characters starting from index 9. So this replaces the character at index `8`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Bash regex:

```
s="1.0.0.0.5"

replacement="6"

[[ $s =~ ^(.*\.)[^.]*$ ]]

echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$replacement"
```

Prints:

```
1.0.0.0.6
```